# Any way to instantiate a generic type in Sorbet? (calling new on type_member)

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'd like to instantiate an instance of the generic type I pass in.  For example,

```
module MyModule
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Generic

  class << self
    extend T::Sig
    extend T::Generic

    Elem = type_member {{ upper: T::Struct }}
    
    sig { returns(Elem) }
    def my_new_struct
      Elem.new
    end
  end
end
```

If I then call `MyModule[SomeStruct].my_new_struct`, this passes Sorbet, but when the code is actually run it crashes with

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<T::Types::TypeMember:0x00007f784b99d4a8 @variance=:invariant>
```

**Is it possible to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

`MyModule[SomeStruct]` resolves to the same `Module` object as just `MyModule`. I.e. the `::[]` operator [just returns `self`](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/master/gems/sorbet-runtime/lib/types/generic.rb#L11-L13). So at runtime, there's no way to distinguish `MyModule[SomeStructA]` from `MyModule[SomeStructB]`

The `[SomeStruct]` syntax only exists to "communicate" with the static Sorbet type-checker, which type-checks the generics. Unfortunately, there's no runtime representation of the concrete types of these type members.

It's possible to kinda hack this together, by implementing a `[]` operator which returns a dynamically-instantiated subclass (this would only work for classes) of `MyModule` which stores the arguments (the concrete values of the type members) as instance variables on the new type.